# Working with a large game world in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

im making a sidescrolling game. Problem is, i've gotten to the point where my gameworld is horizontally wider than the flash stage/workspace. Im wondering how other people handle this, because dragging my movieclips 500 pixels to the left only to change a minor detail, then dragging it back 500 pixels to the position it will have in the game is just too much work.

Answer (score 0):

For sidescrollers, the gameworld itself is usually created by actionscript.
The way you can do it, is to have every "screenfull" of content as it's own object, and then add the content as the player moves through the level.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can scroll while in Flash CS. Second, in most side scrollers, especially potentially infinite, you will not be able to add all the objects you need to the stage, so you will have to either devise an algorithm of placing them at runtime, or repeat a certain sequence of "trials", which can be designed at design time but will have to be pretty short (although they can be wider than the stage).

About placing object at the stage at runtime - you can control which objects you want to be displayed, you can place objects ahead of the stage's visible area, then scroll all of them left with the same speed (if you use a container MC, you can scroll that one, but you will eventually run out of coordinate space with an infinite scroller, so maybe change the container once in a while), then if an object's X (or Y, if vertical scroller) coordinate is too far to the other side of stage, you remove it from display and process.